How to reply emails with original content preserved using smtplib and imaplib
I want to use Python's smtplib and imaplib to implement reading emails (such as Gmail, Exchange) and replying to the original email. What I want to do is read an email, add a new message to the original email while preserving the original message, just like using Gmail's reply function. The new message might be in HTML format. I've searched through smtplib and imaplib documentation but haven't found any similar reply functionality. I can send or reply to emails, but I can only send new messages without being able to retain the original email's content.

I suspect you have to implement this yourself, simply by concatenating your new text with the original text.

There is nothing in the standard library for this, as the layout of the body of an email is not standardized, and they definitely do not deal with the complexities of HTML.  For text, it's reasonably straightforward as you can just concatenate them together (ie, new message,  a line of =====, some headers, and then the original message), but for HTML, you'd probably need to parse the DOM of the reply, and stitch it into your new messages DOM; necessitating some heavy duty HTML libraries.
